# Module does not cache/save in golang test/build process. How do you work around this?

Tags: go, module, go-modules

In one of my projects, using go modules. It has started to continually do a search for a module every single time I do anything. I include lots of modules, but only one does this (see below). How do I work around this?

```
> go test -run TestUodate
go: finding github.com/mohae/deepcopy latest
PASS
ok    example.com/example/stuff   0.698s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This symptom looks like the one in https://golang.org/issue/29773, which is fixed at head (but not in `go1.13beta1` or earlier releases). Try it using a `go` command built from head, which you can obtain easily using the [`gotip`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/dl/gotip) tool.

If you're still seeing this using `gotip`, please open an issue by filling out the template at https://golang.org/issue/new.